# Complete sufficient statistic for $f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{6\theta^4}x^3e^{-x/\theta}$ and the UMVUE for $\theta$

Tags: sufficient-statistics, umvue, complete-statistics

Looking to find a complete sufficient statistic for the following pdf. $X_1, ..., X_n$ from a random sample with distribution:

$$f(x|\theta) = \frac{1}{6\theta^4}x^3e^{-x/\theta}$$

$$ 0 \lt x \lt \infty, 0 \lt \theta \lt \infty$$

I can express this pdf in the exponential form:

$$\exp\left[- \ln6 - 4\ln\theta + 3\ln x - \frac{x}{\theta}\right]$$

Therefore this pdf is part of the exponential family.

$$\prod_{i=1}^n f(x_i|\theta) = \exp\left[-n\ln6 - 4n\ln\theta + 3\sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i - \sum_{i=1}^n \frac{x_i}{\theta}\right]$$

Therefore both $\sum_{i=1}^n \ln x_i$ and $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$ are complete sufficient statistics.

I think that everything I have done so far is correct.

From here, how would I find the UMVUE for $\theta$? Thanks for any help.

Edit: Ok I just realized that this is Gamma($4, \theta$). So that the distribution of $Y = \sum X_i$ is Gamma($4n, \theta$).

So $E[1/Y] = \frac{1}{\theta(4n -1)}$ and $E[\frac{Y}{4n-1}] = \theta$ so $\frac{Y}{4n-1} $is the UMVUE for $\theta$

Would this be correct?

Comment: $\sum_{i=1}^n \log\{x_i\}$ is not connected with any parameter in your density. Therefore the complete minimal sufficient statistic is $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$.

Comment: @Xi'an I just calculated that UMVUE, in this case, will be $\dfrac{\bar X}{4}$ Can you check if I am right? Then I will write it as answer solving thoroughly.